# Записать в массив данные из базы данных

Tags: массивы, php

Здравствуйте! Как можно записать в массив данные из базы данных, при это использовать не `mysql_fatch_array` (о нем я уже знаю) а другой способ и выводить через `foreach`?
Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При запросе к БД, например, через `mysql_query()` тебе возвращается ресурс (тип данных `resource`), и пока ты его не просканируешь функциями типа `mysql_fetch_array`, `mysql_fetch_assoc` или `mysql_fetch_object`, ты ничего толкового не получишь.

Comment: спасибо за уточнение

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще функции `fetch_row() и fetch_assoc()`. Отличие от `fetch_array()` заключается в том, что он выдает сразу ассоциативный и нумерованый массивы, а `fetch_row() и fetch_assoc()` только нумерованый и только ассоциативный соответственно. К тому же рекомендую  взглянуть на класс **mysqli** - он пришел на замену mysql, который уже считается устаревшим.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснение